# XPath and Jabber-RPC

Tags: xml, cocoa, xml-namespaces, xpath

I'm trying to access the methodName element of an XML document using XPATH in Cocoa via the NSXMLElement object.

This is the XML representation of `element`

```
<iq type='set' 
    from='requester@company-b.com/jrpc-client' 
    to='responder@company-a.com/jrpc-server' 
    id='rpc1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:rpc'>
    <methodCall>
      <methodName>examples.getStateName</methodName>
      <params>
        <param>
          <value><i4>6</i4></value>
        </param>
      </params>
    </methodCall>
  </query>
</iq>
```

I've tried,

```
NSArray *nodes = [element nodesForXPath:@"iq/query/methodCall/methodName"
                                  error:&err];
```

but it always returns an empty NSArray.

It works fine without the namespace.

**Solution**

```
/*[name()='iq']/*[name()='query' and namespace-uri()='jabber:iq:rpc']/*[name()='methodCall']/*[name()='methodName']
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation and two alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a FAQ about how to construct an XPath expression agains a document with default namespace**. There are a lot of answers in SO.

The reason for this problem is that

```
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:rpc'>
```

contains a *default namespace* and all of its descendent elements are in this namespace.

**The solution is** either to use location steps of the type:

```
 *[name()='xxx']
```

Then an XPath expression of the kind:

```
*[name()='iq']/*[name()='query']/*[name()='methodCall']/*[name()='methodName']
```

selects the desired nodes.

In even more complicated cases where there are multiple (nested) default namespaces, it may be necessary to use location steps of the kind:

```
*[name()='xxx' and namespace-uri()='theCorrectNamespace']
```

**Or, (recommended)** in the hosting language (usually possible) to register the `'jabber:iq:rpc'` namespace and associate a prefix, say `"x:"` to it.

Then an XPath expression selecting the desired nodes will look like:

```
iq/x:query/x:methodCall/x:methodName
```

where the prefix `"x:"` has been associated to the registered namespace `'jabber:iq:rpc'`.

Comment: I *really* like the recommended, but I can't find anywhere how to register a name space in cocoa. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html

Comment: @Kendall: I don't know anything about Cocoa. Tag your question "xpathengines" and "cocoa" and somebody might happen to provide this information.

Comment: @Dimitre Could you give me an example from another language? Where would I register the namespace? On the Xpath object, the XML element?

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 for a more patient explanation than mine.

Comment: @Kendall Hopkins: Cocoa doesn't have a mothod for registering namespace URI to prefix bindings.

Comment: Could you incorporate my working solution into your answer (to possibly help others). Then I'd be more than happy to accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kendall Hopkins: I don't think your answer could possibly help others, because it's not clear: `/*[name()='iq']/*[name()='query' and namespace-uri()='jabber:iq:jsonrpc']/*[name()='methodCall']/*[name()='methodName']` this means: *a `methodName` element under any default or null namespace (DefOrNullNS), child of a `methodCall` "DefOrNullNS" element, child of a `query` element under default `jabber:iq:jsonrpc` namespace URI, child of `iq` root "DefOrNullNS" element*.

Comment: @Dimitre: Maybe the fact that `fn:name()` results in a QName (implicit in your answer) could leave others to confusion.

Comment: @Alejandro: A person who doesn't have a minimum experience with namespaces will always be confused by anything. :(